# Unexpected Row Count: Actual 0 expected 1?

Tags: java, oracle, persistence, entitymanager

I have a `Java` application and  have created a `Repository` class to query my `Oracle` Database.

The persistence `query` below that I am using is causing an error.

**Query:**

```
Query query = persistence.entityManager().createNativeQuery("Select * from PERSON WHERE ID = ?");
        query.setParameter(1, id);
```

The **error** I am getting is:

```
Error : Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

What could be causing this, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

can you try this?

query = persistence.entityManager().createNativeQuery("Select * from PERSON WHERE ID = ?1");